# Is there a global flag in Spring Boot to disable all the scheduled jobs?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, cron, spring-scheduled

I have two `jobs`, the first one runs every 2 seconds and the second one runs every 10 seconds.
I have their `cron` expressions set in `application.properties` and aware of the fact that each job can be disabled by modifying it's `cron` expression to `"-"` in `application.properties` file.

But would really like to know if there is a global flag available in `Spring Boot` that would disable all `jobs` in single shot?

Tried following and got error at server startup.

**pom.xml**

```
<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>2.2.6.RELEASE</version>
    <relativePath />
</parent>
```

**application.properties**

```
#global flag for all jobs
spring.enable.scheduling=false
jobs.greet.cron=0/2 * * * * ? 
jobs.email.cron=0/10 * * * * ?
```

**DemoApplication.java**

```
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableScheduling
@ConditionalOnProperty(name = "spring.enable.scheduling", matchIfMissing = true, havingValue = "true")
public class DemoApplication {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(DemoApplication.class, args);
    }
}
```

**GreetJob.java**

```
@Component
@Log4j2
public class GreetJob {

    @Scheduled(cron = "${jobs.greet.cron}")
    public void greet() {
        log.info("Starting greet now...");
    }

}
```

**EmailJob.java**

```
@Component
@Log4j2
public class EmailJob {

    @Scheduled(cron = "${jobs.email.cron}")
    public void sendEmail() {
        log.info("Sending email now...");
    }

}
```

**Exception:**

```
2020-05-23 15:51:04,536 ERROR org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication [restartedMain] Application run failed
org.springframework.context.ApplicationContextException: Unable to start web server; nested exception is org.springframework.context.ApplicationContextException: Unable to start ServletWebServerApplicationContext due to missing ServletWebServerFactory bean.
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.onRefresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:156)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:544)
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:141)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:747)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:397)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:315)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1226)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1215)
    at com.example.DemoApplication.main(DemoApplication.java:27)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
    at org.springframework.boot.devtools.restart.RestartLauncher.run(RestartLauncher.java:49)
Caused by: org.springframework.context.ApplicationContextException: Unable to start ServletWebServerApplicationContext due to missing ServletWebServerFactory bean.
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.getWebServerFactory(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:203)
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.createWebServer(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:179)
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.onRefresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:153)
    ... 13 common frames omitted
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By default, there is no such an option, but you can provide the facility with the "global" flag if you put an `@EnableScheduling` on an artificially created configuration with `@Conditional` on it.
This way you won't need to change already defined Scheduled Jobs by putting `@Conditional` on them (`GreetJob` and `EmailJob` in your case) and will provide a single management point for this facility:

So to create that "artificial" configuration, create the following:

```
@Configuration
@EnableScheduling
@ConditionalOnProperty(name="jobs.enabled", havingValue = "true")
public class ConditionalEnableScheduling {
}
```

This way if you start the application with `--jobs.enabled` the conditional will "trigger" and the configuration will load so that the "scheduling infra" will be initialized

General notes (just for the sake of completeness of the answer):

- Remove `@EnableScheduling` from the main class
- Make sure this configuration is scanned (place it next to the main class for example)

Comment: Great your solution worked Mark. Couple of questions to understand this better: 1) Do I need to have the property `jobs.enabled` in `application.properties`? if not, then how do I start the application with that property? 2) Why can't we use `@EnableScheduling` from the main class?

Comment: jobs.enabled is a parameter that can be specified in any way that can be recognized by spring boot application, including application.properties of course. Spring boot can read configuration from many places, in my answer this was just an example.

Comment: @EnabledScheduling annotation is something that imports the infrastructure of scheduling. Check its source code - you'll see the @Import on it. So if you use the suggested solution that already includes `@EnableScheduling` on configuration class, there is no point to put `@EnableScheduling` on the main class (`DemoApplication` in the question) - that's why I've said that it should be removed from the main class.

Comment: Got it. This was the command that I was looking for: `mvn spring-boot:run -Dspring-boot.run.arguments=--jobs.enabled=false`

Answer (score 1):

No. But I'd suggest you to define all job beans as conditional like following:

```
@ConditionalOnProperty(value="jobs.enabled", havingValue = "true", matchIfMissing = true)
@Component
@Log4j2
public class GreetJob {
    ...
}
```

In such case all job beans will be enabled by default, even if property *jobs.enabled* is not defined. Do disable *all* jobs at once you can define property in your application properties file

```
jobs.enabled=false
```

Or define this property in the command line:

```
-Djobs.enabled=false
```

Comment: Thanks for the pointer on showing how to modify the parameter from the command line and run the app.